# How to use the exists keyword in Spring Data to check for the existence of an entity?

Tags: spring-data

How do I use the 'exists' keyword in Spring Data in a query method?

I would like to have a method like this:

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile, Long> {
  boolean existsByAttribute(String attribute);
}
```

where *Attribute* is a field of the *Profile*.

A workaround would be to use a [custom-implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). But the [appendix](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e1910) defines exists as keyword. Could someone give me an example how to use this keyword?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Documented keywords are intended to be used in combination with a property reference. Thus, the semantics of `EXISTS` in this case are that it checks whether the property exists. Note, that the part of the documentation is pulled it from Spring Data Commons and the keyword being listed there doesn't mean it's supported in Spring Data JPA (indicated in the first paragraph of the section you linked). `Exists` is not supported by Spring Data JPA as it only makes sense in MongoDB for example as there's a difference between a field not present entirely and the field available with a logically `null` value.

So what you're looking for seems to be around the `(Is)Null` keyword with the current limitation that it would return objects and you'd have to check the returned list for content. There's a [ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-89) to add support for projections for derived query methods which you might wanna follow for further progress.

Comment: is it still not supported as the documentation implies the opposite. I checked the common docs and jpa and it is contained in both.